# Read XML file in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I try to read XML into data frame in PySpark. From the docs of [Databricks](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#python-api) I figured how to load xml file but returned data frame is empty. Example how I read the file and file that I try to parse is posted below.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 pyspark-shell'
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Stackoverflow')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

sqlc.read \
        .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
        .option('rootTag', 'tags') \
        .option('rowTag', 'row') \
        .load('example.xml')
```

example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName="inclination" Count="18" ExcerptPostId="553" WikiPostId="552" />
  <row Id="3" TagName="exoplanet" Count="219" ExcerptPostId="11" WikiPostId="10" />
</tags>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete `.load(filepath')` and also how are checking if dataframe is empty? A sample xml would also help in debugging.

Comment: @Manoj Singh I added xml and changed misspelling

Comment: I think it can be something with 'com.databricks.spark.xml' class. I don't know where install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [books.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/databricks/spark-xml/master/src/test/resources/books.xml) from spark-xml row tag contains child tags which will be parsed as row fields. In my examples there is no child tags only attributes.
It was the main reason that no error was thrown and result was empty data frame.
I think it should be fixed in the next versions of spark-xml.

I used spark-2.1.0 and spark-xml-0.4.0.